# Select a specific string from a complicated txt in R using dpylr

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, tidyverse

I am trying this for long now. My data frame looks like this:

```
type=c("ID=gene:PFLU_4201;
       biotype=protein_coding;description=putative filamentous adhesin;gene_id=PFLU_4201;
       logic_name=ena", 
       "ID=gene:PFLU_5927;Name=algP1;biotype=protein_coding;
       description=transcriptional regulatory protein algp (alginate regulatory protein algr3);
       gene_id=PFLU_5927;logic_name=ena")

SNP=c(1, 2)

data=data.frame(type, SNP)
```

I would like to isolate from the type column only the string PFLU_*** and my data to look like this

```
type          SNP
PFLU_4201      1
PFLU_5927      2
```

Any help is more than welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ID=gene:PFLU_***` and `gene_id=PFLU_***` are always the same you can use the `mutate` and `str_extract` functions from the `dplyr` and `stringr` packages, Both are part of `tidyverse`.

```
require(tidyverse)
data<-data %>% 
  mutate(type = str_extract(type,"\\bPFLU_[:digit:]+\\b"))
```

This results in:

```
       type SNP
1 PFLU_4201   1
2 PFLU_5927   2
```

If there are times when they are not the same you can use `str_extract_all`, `map_chr`, `str_c` and `unique`. `map_chr` is found in the `purrr` package, which is also part of `tidyverse`.

```
require(tidyverse)
data<-data %>% 
  mutate(type = map_chr(str_extract_all(type,"\\b(PFLU_[:digit:]+)+\\b"), ~ str_c(unique(.x), collapse=", ")))
```

This will create comma separated string with all instances that match `PFLU_` followed by a the adjacent number for each `type` string.

Changing the second `PFLU_5927` to `PFLU_0000` would result in:

```
                  type SNP
1            PFLU_4201   1
2 PFLU_5927, PFLU_0000   2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just use `sub` here for a base R option:

```r
data$type <- sub("^.*\\b(PFLU_\\d+)\\b.*$", "\\1", data$type)
data

       type SNP
1 PFLU_4201   1
2 PFLU_5927   2
```

The sample data used was the same you provided in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try This:

```
library(stringr)
new_data <- data %>% mutate(
  type = substr(type,str_locate(type,"PFLU_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")[,"start"],
                str_locate(type,"PFLU_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")[,"end"]))
```

If you want to get more than one `PFLU _ ****` per line, you can use the `str_locate_all` function.